# Point Forum, like bbpress, to existing database

Tags: php, mysql, forum

I have an existing database with a users table and questions/answers table. I'd like to use bbpress (or any forum really) as a front end for this for access via the web. Is this possible? Has anyone done this?

Look forward to the responses. Thanks!

Comment: How did you generate the existing database?

Comment: It's actually a database that is accessed via a php script for an iPhone App. The database and tables were created manually and php designed to work with the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT (Taking int consideration your comments):

You can actually do this but it may not be easy.

In first place if you want to access your database remotely you should enable remote acces.

BUT: Unless the databases have exactly the same structure you this will be a very complicated process since you would have to seriously mod the BB forum.

If you dont want them in sync (which would) much easier, you can export you Iphones database and modify it so that it fits into the forum one.

This could take some time but is definitely easier than modifying the forum itself. Everything you "touch" will have consequences.

To sum up, I could recommend you [PubBB](http://punbb.informer.com/) it is a simple but powerful forum that may easier to manipulate.

Good luck!!

Comment: Yes, it's MySQL database (the existing one). I want to point the bbpress forum to my existing tables, which have the user info and questions/answers. I looked through some of the php code, but it's no clear where the mapping is happening

Comment: Would you settle with exporting it and adapt it and import it to bbpress? would that be good enough? becuse I cannot understand what do you mean by point!

Comment: My iPhone app is currently using the database, I can't change the current table structure or it will mess the iPhone app up. So, I was hoping to change bbpress from using bb_users table and use ip_users instead.

Comment: No problem at all!! If you need any EDIT because something is not clear do ask! good luck!